# Magento 1 - How to get credit memo / refunds without specifying a specific order?

Tags: refund

Magento 1

I'm trying to get some of the latest refunds issued in magento by timestamp.
I want to be able to get them WITHOUT specifying any specific order.
How do I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
$creditmemo = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection')  
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC') // order by timestamp
    ->setPage(1, 1) // limit to one item for an efficiency query
    ->getFirstItem(); // or ->getLastItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to kiatng's answer, including other details as an example.

```
$current_page = 1;
$page_size = 100;

$creditmemos_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC') // order by timestamp
  ->setPage($current_page, $page_size)
;

foreach ($creditmemos_collection as $creditmemo) {  

  $creditmemo->getBaseAdjustmentPositive();
  // and other properties

  $order = $creditmemo->getOrder();
  $order->getIncrementId();
  // and other properties

  $items_collection = $creditmemo->getItemsCollection();
  foreach ($items_collection as $item) { 
    $item->getSku();
    // and other properties
  } 
}
```